# What percentage do I need to pass my exam?

Tags: percentages

I have to get 60% to pass my course.
It is split between gradings of:
10% for participation;
30% for essay;
60% for exam.

I have so far recieved
50/100 for my participation - so 50%
30/100 for my essay - 30%
and am yet to sit my exam.

What do I need in my exam to achieve 60% overall, or is it impossible?

Thank you

Comment: You have 14 points so far (5 for the participation, 9 for the essay) so you need another 46.  The final is worth 60 so you need to get 46/60 or 76.6%

Comment: It sounds like you are a bit behind in your studies, so you may need to study hard to get that 76.6%.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

So far you have $0,5*10 + 0,3*30 = 14$. You need to get $46$ from the rest $60 \rightarrow \frac{46}{60}= 76,6...$%.

Comment: In other words 76.6%.

Comment: Edited it since a second, thanks. :)